# Python - Identify a string and print all that statement from a text file

Tags: python, string, nlp

I've a text file with following text:

```
The process runs very well||
It starts at 6pm and ends at 7pm||
The user_id is 23456||
This task runs in a daily schedule!!
```

I'm trying to see extract all the lines that have the string "user_id". Basically I want to extract this:

```
The user_id is 23456
```

My current python code only identify if the desired string exists (or not) in the text file:

```
word = 'user_id'
if word in open('text.txt').read():
    print(word)
else:
    print("Not found")
```

How can I print all the sentences with that contains the word?

Thanks!

Comment: Iterating over `open(...)` is iterating over individual lines.

Comment: First, make sure to load the text file in a list, where every entry is one line, represented as a string. You can google how to do it. Then, you can simply use `if word in line: print(line)` to get the lines when you iterate over them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to iterate over the lines to find what you want

```
word = 'user_id'

with open('text.txt', 'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if word in line:
            print(line)
```

You are not printing the line, only the word that you are trying to match. Note, the `with open()` is a nicer way to handle opening and closing files and is functionally *similar* (but not the same) to

```
fh = open('text.txt', 'r')
# for loop here
fh.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do a for loop and iterate through every line, checking if the `word` is `in` the line.

```
word = 'user_id'
for line in open('mean_temp.txt'):
    if word in line:
        print(line)
```

output:

```
The user_id is 23456||
```

Comment: It's safer to use the context manager `with open(file) as fh` so you don't have to manually close the handle later

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
word = 'user_id'
not_found = True
with open('text.txt', 'r') as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if word in line:
            print(line)

if not_found:
    print("Not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what regular expressions are built for:

```
 import re
 with open('text.txt','r') as f:
      text = f.read()
      sentences = re.findall(r'(.*user.*)',text)
 if len(sentences) > 0:
      for sentence in sentences:
           print(sentence)
 else:
      print('Not found')
```

Comment: I just saw the other anser. It will produce the same result, but with larger datasets, I believe this answer should be faster. Regular expressions also gives a lot of flexibility in what you are looking for.